# ios swift parse: pickerview use array or dictionaries

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, parse-platform

I am selecting some simple data from parse.com in order to fill a PickerView with it.

I have an "objectId" and a "name". This data I want to populate int my PickerView.

First I loaded the data into an array, which works fine... The PickerView is displaying the data the right way.

But as I want to save the selection from the pickerView to parse, I need the objectId of the selected language item - in this case the objectId.

When I use a dictionary:

```
var languagePickerValues = [String : String]()

// within the query loop
self.languagePickerValues[object.objectId] = name
```

I get errors here:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return languagePickerValues[row]
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
        selectedLanguage.text = languagePickerValues[row]
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

as these functions try to access an array with an Int as numeric key which I don't have when working with dictionary.

For displaying purpose I could work with the array...
To save the data to the API I need the objectId...

What would be the right thing to do?

Comment: I don't get it at all -- only that you deal with parse... sorry

Comment: Basically: What is the right way to pull data from parse (table1) to populate a PickerView and to get the selected item to save its objectId back to parse (table2). Does this makes it more transparent?

Answer (score 0):

what is `object.objectId` ? if its int or some other numeric type, then try:

```
self.languagePickerValues["\(object.objectId)"] = name
```

its because dictionary keys are strings, so just convert them with his:

```
"\(object.objectId)"
```

Comment: object.objectId is a string (strange, I know, but this is parse.com)

Comment: I could change the titleForRow row function to this: titleForRow row: String but how can I get the selected key and value in function didSelectRow? I would need the dictionary key for database reason and the dictionary value for displaying purpose...